# CMake not properly include directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I just wanted to create executable from this, https://github.com/petrachor/petrachor/tree/master/ethkey

I created a folder 'build' (sub directory), and inside it I tried the following:

> cmake ..
>
> make

I got this below error message:

```
ethkey/main.cpp:26:10: fatal error: libdevcore/FileSystem.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libdevcore/FileSystem.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I therefore decided to try and write my own cmake file, which is below. However, I got the same error message.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(petrachor-key)

set(ETHCORE "../libethcore"
    CACHE PATH "The path to ethcore.")

set(DEVCORE "../libdevcore"
    CACHE PATH "The path to ethcore.")

add_executable(petrachor-key KeyAux.h main.cpp)


set( lib_build_DIR ../libethcore/outputs )

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${lib_build_DIR})

add_subdirectory(${ETHCORE} ${lib_build_DIR}) 

add_library( lib_libethcore STATIC IMPORTED )

include_directories(${ETHCORE})

set( lib_build_DEV_DIR ../libdevcore/outputs )

file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${lib_build_DEV_DIR})

add_subdirectory(${DEVCORE} ${lib_build_DEV_DIR}) 

add_library( lib_libdevcore STATIC IMPORTED )

include_directories(${DEVCORE})

target_link_libraries(petrachor-key lib_libethcore lib_libdevcore )
```

This is the folder tree:

```
ethkey  // This is the folder where I am making the executable

libdevcore // library source files

libethcore // library source files
```

What would like to make my cmake file to compile, what and what should I have to it?

Comment: In order to include `libdevcore/FileSystem.h` you have to include direcotry that has `libdevcore` inside. `include_directories(${ETHCORE}/..)`

Comment: Thanks ... it worked but along the way the it flagged again , libdevcore/FileSystem.h No such file or directory
 #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>.  But  boost is included in cmake file,https://github.com/petrachor/petrachor/blob/master/libdevcore/CMakeLists.txt. What should I do to get boost included?

Comment: The `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` may be empty

Comment: @KamilCuk, I just stalled Boost, and that particular error is gone.  But I got a new issue, No rule to make target 'lib_libethcore-NOTFOUND', needed by 'petrachor-key'.  Stop.

Comment: `lib_libethcore` was not found. You seem to use `find_package(lib_libethcore)` or something similar. And it doesn't find `lib_libethcore`.